# Linux Shared Library link error (undefined symbol)

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, shared-libraries

I'm using a shared library that depends on another one. libA.so uses libB.so. All files are compiled with -fPIC. Linking uses -shared. When i call dlopen on libA.so it cannot find symbols in libB.so, i get the "undefined symbol" error.

> dlopen(/usr/share/orthanc/plugins/libA.so) failed: Error
>   /usr/local/lib/libB.so: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN3Aws5Utils6Stream34DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethodEv

ldd returns:

```
libA.so:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc35b61000)
libB.so => /usr/local/lib/libB.so (0x00007fdb04999000)
libawss3cpp.so => /usr/local/lib/libawss3cpp.so (0x00007fdb0424b000)
libjsoncpp.so => /usr/local/lib/libjsoncpp.so (0x00007fdb03fd7000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdb03c55000)
```

when i try to find this symbol in the lib it returns this:

> nm -gC libB.so | grep DefaultResponse
>   Aws::Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod()

I get a file not found error when i delete libB.so.

Comment: Do you know in which library `Aws::Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod()` is defined?

Comment: Are your `-l` flags the last arguments to the compiler? In your response from `nm`, does that symbol have a `T` in front of it, or something else?

Comment: yes i used -l as the last arguments. the letter that appears before the symbol is U

Answer (score 1):

I asked in the comments if the output of `nm` listed a `T` or something else as its value. You replied that it was `U`. `U` stands for *undefined*. This means that the symbol in question is only referenced by this library (i.e., the code for `Aws::Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod()`is **not** part of `libB.so`).

Find the library that actually defines the symbol and link that library as well.